# Validate decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, decimal

hi  i want to know how to write a validation code for a number with two decimal places for example 45.80

```
function submitform4()
{

    var min=00.01;
    var max = 100.00;
    var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('valid').value);

    console.log(num);

    if (min > num || max < num) {
        alert(num + ' is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
    return false;
    }
}
```

this is something i copied from my work and thought i could change it but didnt really work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to validate? And what isn't working? Are we to assume `45.80` is the value stored in `#AgeGrade`? If so, maybe your problem is trying to parse it as an `Int` (whole number)

Comment: basically i dont have a proper script for it. the script above was me trying something, but what am trying to do is to add a number with two decimal places, and i dont know how to start the code, hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, still quite confused. "i dont have a proper script for it" <- for what? "add a number" <- add a number to what?

Comment: `parseInt` just parses integers. If you want to accept numbers with a decimal point, use `parseFloat`. How important is it that they enter 2 decimal places?

Comment: It is not important, if they enter 2 decimal places, all i'm trying to do is when they enter a number it should convert to decimals e.g. 99 becomes 99.00, I also want an error massage if a number above 100 is entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is what I'd do, If I understand correctly.

This addresses a few issues:

- JavaScript doesn't like the numeric value `00.01`. Use `0.01` instead
- use `parseFloat` on your `input` value. `parseInt` will round to an integer
- return `true` if successful (not undefined)

---

```
function submitform4() {
    var MIN = 0.01;
    var MAX = 100.00;

    var input = document.getElementById('AgeGrade');
    var inputValue = parseFloat(input.value);

    var is_valid = (MIN > inputValue || MAX < inputValue);

    if (is_valid) {
        input.value = inputValue.toFixed(2); // set to 2 decimal places
        return true
    } else {
        alert(inputValue + ' is not between ' + MIN + ' and ' + MAX);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working, when i'm adding it to my script, its actually messing it up and even the other parts of the scripts stops working :( it there something that i'm missing ? what shall i add in the HTML part?

Comment: i know im asking for to many questions but i really appropriate your help

Comment: Thats ok. I had a syntax error (`==` instead of `=`). I really need to start checking my code haha. Let me know how far that gets you now

Comment: Just made another update to deal with adjusting your input value to display 2 decimal places. `toFixed(n)` converts the number to a string representation with `n` decimal places

Comment: @Zack L, well that looks much better, its not messing my work anymore but its still not giving me an error when i enter a number out of the range, what shall i put in the form action e.g. onsubmit, input type and onclick?

Comment: Well... thats sort of another whole can of worms. Really, your action should just be whatever you're trying to actually *do* with the form, and the validation should be done with "unobtrusive" javaScript. i.e. attaching events for `keyup`, `submit`, or `change` onto your form or input field. Really depends on your goals for this thing. Honestly, I'm more of a jQuery-guy myself, and I can't off the top of my head give examples for event-binding in vanilla JS. I suggest getting organized, figuring out exactly what you want, taking a stab at it, and then asking another question if need be. Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function submitForm(numberToEvaluate){
    var min = 0.0;
    var max = 100;

    //Instead of being passed in
    //This would be grabbed from DOM element
    var num = numberToEvaluate;


    console.log(num);

    if (min > num || max < num) {
        alert(num + ' is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
        return false;
    }
}

submitForm(-1);
submitForm(37);
```

Comment: Javascript has an issue with number values having more than one 0 before the decimal point.

Comment: what do i need to put in the HTML part?

Comment: Are you trying to test in jsfiddle? In that case, the html would contain the DOM element you are getting the value from.

Answer (score 0):

I would try parseFloat() :

```
function submitform4()
{
  var min = parseFloat("00.01");
  var max = parseFloat("100.00");
  var num = parseFloat("200.20");
  console.log(num);
  if (min > num || max < num) {
    alert(num + ' is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
    console.log('false');
  }
}
submitform4();
```

See [Feedle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFyU7/4/)

Else you certainly have error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

See **not working** [Feedle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rs9N6/1/)

Comment: AFAIK JavaScript has only ONE number type.
you're just adding an additional step. Right? Why would you want to start as a string?

Comment: @Zach L: because the OP is asking about validation of the value in an `<input>`

Comment: Its my impression that `min` and `max` are *constants*, not input. He's looking up the value of `#ageGrade` which I think is safe to assume is the input. You do have an important point though. `min=00.01` is broken. He would need to change this to `min=0.01`.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine (almost), depending on how you intend to use i the function.

If you are using the function as a validation before you submit, like `if(submitform4())` then you need to add `return true;` to the end of the function to return true unless the answer is false.